# Swift clarification about optional with NSDictionary and valueForKey

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary, option-type

I'm trying to learn Swift porting my Obj-C code that manage an HttpRequest, but when I receive the response in JSON I've issue trying to access the NSDictionary.

Example of JSON:

```
{
    response =     {
        id = 1234;
        name = a2b3n4h5lkl3;
    };
}
```

I receive from HttpRequest completionHandler

```
(dictionary:NSDictionary?, error:NSError?) -> Void
```

than I want to get some values from the NSDictionary? and save them to a var:

```
let responseDictionary = dictionary!.valueForKey("response") as? NSDictionary

println(responseDictionary!)                        // The informations are present correctly

if (responseDictionary!.count > 0) {

    var testStringAccessId:NSString? = responseDictionary!.valueForKey("id")! as? NSString

    println(testStringAccessId)                     // print nil

    println(responseDictionary!.valueForKey("id")!) // print the correct value

    if let stringAccessId = responseDictionary!.valueForKey("id")! as? NSString {
        self.accessID = stringAccessId
    } else {
        println("Error No Access ID")               // Enter here
        completion(success: false)
        return                                      // The function exit with error
    }
}
```

I tried many combination but maybe I'm missing something in the optional use. The strange thing it's that if I comment the return in the error case and try to get another value from the NSDictionary this one is correct, like:

```
if let stringAccessNAME = responseDictionary!.valueForKey("name")! as? NSString {
    self.accessNAME = stringAccessNAME              // I get the correct value saved in the variable
} else {
    println("Error No Access NAME")
    completion(success: false)
    return
}
```

Any help please?

Thanks
Ale

**SOLVED**:

Use NSNumber instead of NSString. Thanks to Jesper

Comment: Sounds like you aren't correctly targeting the `id` value in your JSON. Some sample JSON would help show the issue.

Comment: Edited with a JSON example

Comment: It doesn't seem like the `id` value is a string but a number. Try `NSNumber` instead of `NSString` - and instead of guessing like I am (since I have to, I don't have access to running code), check the values and types in the debugger.

Comment: Thanks Jesper you are absolutely right, I changed to NSNumber and works.

Answer (score 0):

As you properly stated in your question after the edit, your ID is not store as a String (or NSString) trying to cast a string to an NSNumber will return a value of nil.

```
var testStringAccessId:NSNumber? = responseDictionary!.valueForKey("id")! as? NSNumber
```

This is the correct syntax to use here.

I might want to add that you are unwrapping the dictionary before checking it. You might want to add a check there, what happens if you can’t connect to the internet, or when your API crashes? There are very few times where you really have to use the `!`